# Use group in rails when you use nested of nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by, nested-attributes

I have this models

point -> belongs_to :days

days  -> belongs_to :routes

and I would like to group by point `:address` all the point of one kind of route, I can get all:

```
Point.includes(:day => :route).where(days:{routes:{place: "Dublin"}})
```

but if I try to use `group(:address)`, I find this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column 
"points.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an 
aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  "points"."id" AS t0_r0, "points"."title" AS t0_r1, 
"...
```

Could you help me? thanks

Comment: Can you please paste all fields of your models? Because you mentioned only models and then you referer different fields without any datails. I think I can help you, but I need a bit more details from you

Comment: Can you try `.to_sql` so that you can get the SQL query generated before and after the `group` method?

Comment: Can you try to change it to inner join relationship using `joins` instead of `includes`, then add points.id in group clause `.group(:address, 'points.id')`